# Unit tests and multiple async tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm creating unit tests to assist with building some code which will accept and queue (if needed) inbound requests from my controller.

In my unit test I want two lines of code to fire off pretty much at the same time, albeit with a 2 second delay between the calls.  This allows the first branch of my logic to be triggered, then on the second call because the passed data is already seen the alternate branch of logic is used.

I've come close but it feels messy.  I'm using the following which immediately passes off my first call and moves on to the subsequent lines of code.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => stubbedQueueHandler.QueueProcessor(setupModel));

Thread.Sleep(2000);
//second call
stubbedQueueHandler.QueueProcessor(setupModel);

await Task.Delay(10000);
```

However the unit test concludes ahead of the first call finishing, which in turn kills the process.  The only way to allow the first call to complete is to put an `await Task.Delay()` line which does the trick.

I can see why it's doing it, because I've effectively handed off the call with no expectation of a response coming back.  I don't want to start using task delays and I'm sure it's just my lack of understanding that's the problem when it comes to async programming :o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to capture the `Task` which kicks off `QueueProcessor` and await it after calling the stub for the second time:

```
public async Task FooTestAsync()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => stubbedQueueHandler.QueueProcessor(setupModel));
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    stubbedQueueHandler.QueueProcessor(setupModel);
    await task;
}
```

This way, you ensure the completion of the operation before the operation completes, given that the `QueueProcessor` will synchronously block until its operation is complete.

Answer (score 4):

You need to avoid using Thread.Sleep() with your async code.

Refer to [Figure 5 The “Async Way” of Doing Things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

> ```
> To Do This                                Instead of This            Use This
> Retrieve the result of a background task  Task.Wait or Task.Result   await
> Wait for any task to complete             Task.WaitAny               await Task.WhenAny
> Retrieve the results of multiple tasks    Task.WaitAll               await Task.WhenAll
> Wait a period of time                     Thread.Sleep               await Task.Delay
> ```
>
> you should avoid mixing async and blocking code. Mixed async and blocking code can cause deadlocks, more-complex error handling and unexpected blocking of context threads.

Comment: Good point, a bad habit I started to get in to, will nip that in the bud for the future! :o)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the OPs question.